# The Remorhaz in the Glacial Rift of the Frost Giant Jarl

Tags: adnd-1e

In room 28 of the first level there is a Remorhaz with 58 hit points.
How many hit dice does it has? The AD&D Monster Manual says 7 to 14 HD. It definitely not 7 HD (d8 x 7 = max of 56).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The adventure says it is a 30' long remorhaz, and the MM entry clearly details how the remorhaz' HD and length are related (HD*3), therefore it is a 10 HD remorhaz.